# Javascript function requires 2 clicks to execute

Tags: javascript

When a user clicks the image, it partially fires the javascript with the confirm alert message. On the 2nd click, the remaining javascript completes where it gets my function and deletes the record. I want the entire script to execute on one click (not two). What is wrong with my code?

```
<img id="#id#" src="images/delete.gif" width="16" height="16" title="Delete letter" class="delete" />
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table td img.delete')
        .live('click', function() {
            var currentRow = $(this); 
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this letter?")){
                $.get('cfc/letters.cfc?method=deleteLetter&returnformat=plain', 
                        { id: $(this).attr('id') },
                        function(returnMsg){
                            if(returnMsg.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')==='ok'){
                                $(currentRow).parent().parent().remove();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What an awesome code, that **machine can read, but humans cannot**, kindly rewrite it to make it legible.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, me fix this :-D

Comment: To answer you question, what jQuery version you are using? *Also, it takes some time to process the AJAX request.*

Comment: @Grundy That's awesome! `:)`

Comment: Seems like your AJAX request just takes a while to respond. Code seems correct.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to remove confirmation and proceed with deletion on image click immediately

Comment: Grundy, thanks for rewriting this.. I had trouble formatting:) Praveen, I am using version: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.4.2.min.js"></script>. I also tried the CDN 1.4.2 links, along with different jquery versions. The different versions do no work at all. I tried waiting up to 5 minutes.. but the wait time does not seem to matter. Either it works right away or it does not. Sometimes it works, but mostly it takes 2 clicks to execute. Any other suggestions? Thanks everyone so much!!!!

Comment: Artem, yes - when user clicks 'ok' on confirmation, I want the deletion to occur immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pranshant Palikhe's comment, Ajax requests, by their very nature of being asynchronous, could take a while to execute.

It is very likely that what you perceive as a second click action is actually the first click's callback receiving a response and executing the row removal on the DOM.

To confirm this, I'd suggest you click on the delete image once and wait. I don't know what timeout you've set, but two minutes should be a worse scenario long-enough wait.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for some time after click and see the network tab in developer tools to confirm if you are getting data.

If everything is correct then you are getting data very lately.